# Performance Of 51Degrees Mobi Foundation 1.2.0.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, 51degrees

When I run visual studio 2010's performance wizard for CPU utilization of my site it shows me 51 degrees related call tree as a hot path.

My application is MVC3 Razor. Please let me know are there any known performance issues of 51degrees Mobi Foundation 1.2.0.5 library.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try version 2.0 and advise if this is still a concern. We've changed the code to improve performance.